# Update merging two directories

Tags: shell, directory, make, file-copy

First, note that this is *not* a plain 'merge two directories', this is a question about how to keep the merge of said directories updated when the sources change.

Let us say that I have two directories `a` and `b` and I want to merge them into `c` with the following rules:

- Entries from `a` must always be in `c` regardless of their existence or last modified timestamp.
- Fill the gaps with `b`.

A simple `cp` from `b` to `c` and overwriting with `a` where necessary does the job (copies more than necessary, but it is intended to be used only once)

Now, what I want is some way of keeping this updated (as this is intended to be in a `Makefile`) So, if there is a new file in `a`, `make` copies it. If there is a new file in `b`, `make` copies it *only* if it is not already in `c`. If a file from `a` is updated, `make`, updates it in `c` and if a file from `b` is updated, it is updated in `c` *only* if it came from `b` but *not* if it came from `a`.

I hope I have explained it accurately.

Comment: What have you tried? Why is `make` the tool you've chosen for this?

Comment: I haven't tried much, and right now, I have a `rm` followed by two copies. It works, but it needs to copy everything even if just a tiny thing changed. `cp -u` works for the copy from `a` but only in the cases where the file from `b` is older than the one in `a` so it is not fully reliable. `make`has been chosen just as a 'wrapper' as this is intended to be used as `make update`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to reach the required state. You can use the following 2 commands:

```
rsync -auv b/ c/
rsync -av a/ c/
```

**PROS:** it works recursively for all sub-directories tree.

**CONS:** at the period of time from moment you start the first command and until the end of second command execution, some newer files from  "b/" having analogue in "a/" can be temporarily placed into "c/", until they are replaced by the correct files from "a/" by second command.

So, the solution is good only if:

- you need the end result and not care about the "c/" state during sync procedure;
- if you do not care about some files to be copied extra times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Makefile` as a start.

I tested it a bit with GNU Make 4.2.1. I don't know if it will work with other Make versions. I know that it will fail if there is a subdirectory in `a` or `b`. Maybe there are other pitfalls.

```
.PHONY: all

SRCA = a
SRCB = b

DEST = c

# create list of targets from wildcard lists of both sources
TARGETS = $(patsubst $(SRCA)/%,$(DEST)/%,$(wildcard $(SRCA)/*)) $(patsubst $(SRCB)/%,$(DEST)/%,$(wildcard $(SRCB)/*)) 

all: $(TARGETS)

# GNU Make prefers the first matching pattern rule because both rules lead to the same stem length 
$(DEST)/%:$(SRCA)/%
    cp "$<" "$@"

# alternative pattern rule if the first one does not match
$(DEST)/%:$(SRCB)/%
    cp "$<" "$@"
```